# How to get information about the android device color depth, how many colors the display has?

Tags: android, system-information

Is there a possibility to get information about the android device display color depth through the SDK?

By color depth I mean 16m colors , 256K colors and so on.

I know that this meta data is probably useless , but my client wants to get this info and I can't find a way to get it.

Thanks everyone.